# how to populate a dropdownlist based on another dropdownlist selected value in mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created two Drop Down List. On selecting a value from first dropdown list second dropdown list should be filled this is my code in View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.DropDownList("Id", ViewData["Id"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { })
    <button type="submit">next</button>
} 
@Html.DropDownList("Id", ViewData["Id1"] as List<SelectListItem>)
```

When I click on next button second dropdown is getting populated. Same thing I want to do when I select a particular item from first list. I don't want to use jquery is there any way to do?
Or is there any way how I can generate postback when I select value from first list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can put the first dropdown inside a form and include the change attribute to this dropdown:

```
@{ Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }); }

    @Html.DropDownList("Id", ViewData["Id"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })

@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

Then, in the controller, you should include some code to populate the second dropdown.

Comment: I have taken it in form but then im not getting "onchange" can you please provide me with code. It will be very helpful

Comment: your method was working fine but now I am having some issue with it can you please help me out [Here] is my problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935623/how-to-populate-a-drop-down-list-based-on-another-drop-down-list-selected-value)