# Populate a drop down list based on another drop down list selected value in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have referred [This ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675636/how-to-populate-a-dropdownlist-based-on-another-dropdownlist-selected-value-in-m) of stackoverflow It is working fine but since i have taken drop down list in forms so when second dropdown list gets populate selected value in first dropdown list is getting effected. How to maintain that value??

Here is my code.

**View**

```
@{ Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }); }
@Html.DropDownList("country", ViewData["Id"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
@{ Html.EndForm(); }


@{ Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }); }
@Html.DropDownList("state", ViewData["Id1"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
@{ Html.EndForm(); }


@{ Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }); }
@Html.DropDownList("city", ViewData["Id2"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        FillCountry();
        FillState();
        FillCity();
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(User ur)
    {
        string str = @"Data Source=DEV_3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_Naved_Test;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        string query = "Insert into tblTest (Name,Email,MobileNo) values('" + ur.Name + "','" + ur.Email + "','" + ur.MobileNo + "')";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        TempData["msg"] = "<script>alert('Inserted Successfully');</script>";
        ModelState.Clear();
        FillCountry();
        FillState();
        FillCity();
        return View();


    }
    public void FillCountry()
    {
        string str = @"Data Source=DEV_3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_Naved_Test;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        string query = "select * from tblCountry ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = rdr[1].ToString(), Value = rdr[0].ToString() });
        }
       
        ViewData["Id"] = li;
        
    }
    public void FillState()
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt16(Request["country"]);
        string str = @"Data Source=DEV_3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_Naved_Test;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        string query = "select * from tblState where cid='" + id + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = rdr[1].ToString(), Value = rdr[0].ToString() });
        }
        ViewData["Id1"] = li;
    }
    public void FillCity()
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt16(Request["state"]);
        string str = @"Data Source=DEV_3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_Naved_Test;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        string query = "select * from tbl_cities where StateId='" + id + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = rdr[1].ToString(), Value = rdr[0].ToString() });
        }
        ViewData["Id2"] = li;
    }
```

and also when I am using only two dropdownlist i.e `ddlCountry` and `ddlState` and select Country from `ddlCountry` my `ddlSates` is getting populated properly but the selected Country from `ddlCountry` is getting changed.

Comment: Not relevant to issue but try to avoid query construction using string concatenation instead use parameterized query to avoid danger of SQL Injection.

Comment: @downvoter any reason for voting it down??

Comment: @downvoter Yes, this might be a bad question, but how do you explain to the OP why?

Comment: @Navy I didn't vote it down.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya can you please elaborate. I dint understand since im very new to MVC

Comment: @Navy [How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Comment: `int id = Convert.ToInt16(Request["Id1"]);` will fail because you do not have a control with a name attribute `name="Id1"` so `Request["Id1"]` will always be null. I'm guessing your model does not have a property named `Id` so your not binding to anything, it which case you need to set the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem`. I very strongly recommend you go to the MVC site and work through some basic tutorials.

Comment: @ Jenish Rabadiya or can you provide me with any simpler way how to populate my dropdownlist?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Sir but I am getting value in Id1 and based on that my ddlState is getting populated properly

Comment: @Navy, then you have a typo in your question - the second dropdown must be `@Html.DropDownList("Id1", ...)` - not `"Id"`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Thanx Sir actually that typo is not in question it was in my code. Now list is getting populated but previous slected value is not maintained can you please help me with that

Comment: @Navy you can use [Selected Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.selected(v=vs.118).aspx) of `SelectListItem` class for maintaining the selected options.

Comment: I pointed out how to do that in my first comment. But your code incorporates every worst possible practice in MVC I can think of. You need to learn some basics before you go any further.

Comment: Thanks   Jenish Rabadiya and  Stephen Muecke for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did this and it working perfect

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string str = @"Data Source=DEV_3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_Naved_Test;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        string query = "select * from tbl_country ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = rdr[1].ToString(), Value = rdr[0].ToString() });
        }
        ViewData["country"] = li;
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult StateList(int Id)
    {
        string str = @"Data Source=DEV_3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_Naved_Test;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        string query = "select * from tbl_states where cid='" + Id + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = rdr[1].ToString(), Value = rdr[0].ToString() });
        }
        return Json(li, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public JsonResult Citylist(int id)
    {
        string str = @"Data Source=DEV_3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_Naved_Test;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        string query = "select * from tbl_cities where stateid='" + id + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = rdr[1].ToString(), Value = rdr[0].ToString() });
        }
        return Json(li, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ @Html.DropDownList("Country", ViewData["country"] as SelectList, "Select Country", new { id = "Country", style = "width: 150px;" })<br />
<select id="State" name="state" , style="width: 150px;"></select><br />
<select id="city" name="City" , style="width: 150px;"></select><br />
}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/jscript">
$(function ()
{
    $('#Country').change(function ()
    {        
        $.getJSON('/Cascading/StateList/' + $('#Country').val(), function (data)
        {
            var items = '<option>Select State</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, state)
            {
                items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#State').html(items);
        });
    });

    $('#State').change(function ()
    {
        $.getJSON('/Cascading/Citylist/' + $('#State').val(), function (data)
        {
            var items = '<option>Select City</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, city)
            {
                items += "<option value='" + city.Value + "'>" + city.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#city').html(items);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: how do you get value of city and state in action without the use of json

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery like below

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
/*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
$(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
}
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
$('#select2').html(options);
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<option value="1">Fruit</option>
<option value="2">Animal</option>
<option value="3">Bird</option>
<option value="4">Car</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="select2">
<option value="1">Banana</option>
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="1">Orange</option>
<option value="2">Wolf</option>
<option value="2">Fox</option>
<option value="2">Bear</option>
<option value="3">Eagle</option>
<option value="3">Hawk</option>
<option value="4">BWM<option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="validationCustom04">
                  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LGAID)</label>
                       <select id="LocalID" name="LocalID" 
                     class="form-control" 
                  data-val="true" 
               data-val-number="Select Local Government">
                           <option value="0">---Select--</option>
                       </select>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LGAID, "", new { @class = "text text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Providing an explanation for code-only answers generally makes them more useful. Start by stating how your answer is complementing/enhancing the previous answers, or whether it can be used as a new method to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
                  $("#State").change(function() {
               var Id = $("#localID option:Selected").val();
             $.getJSON('/ControllerName/ActionName/' + Id, 
           function (data) {
           var AddItem = '<option value="">---select from list--</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, local) {
            AddItem += "<option value='" + local.LGAID + "'>" + local.LGAName + " 
            </option>"
        });

        $('#LocalID').html(AddItem);
           });
        });
```

Comment: Could you please explain how your code answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

```
[Route("PersonalData/localGoverntment")]
public ActionResult ActionName(int Id)
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

    List<LGA> LocalList = db.LGAs.ToList();
    List<LocalGModel> localModel = LocalList.Where(x => x.StateID == Id).Select(x => new LocalGModel { LGAID = x.LGAID, LGAName = x.LGAName }).ToList();

    return Json(localModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```